# Why my "too broad" flag was declined in this question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, flagging

[How to better secure vagrant virtual machines and delete vagrant user](https://superuser.com/questions/1269990/how-to-better-secure-vagrant-virtual-machines-and-delete-vagrant-user)

This post asks 2 questions at the same time:

1. Is there a better way to do this with a first-and-one-time `vagrant up` command?
2. Is there a way around that (... the process never completes ...)

As I understand how the SE works, asking two different questions in a post is closable as "too broad". These two questions, although has common background, are different and should have different solution.

**Why was my flag declined?**

I'm expecting to better understand the culture of SuperUser.

Comment: +1 for *I'm expecting to better understand the culture of SuperUser.* That means you are well on your way to making a positive difference on SU.

Comment: You should have seen [this one on mechanics.stackexchange.com](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/posts/49978/revisions), nine questions! But they were all generally related to their brakes so not really that different, and a moderator generally agreed, adding "*go ahead and ask as many questions as you like. Just be aware that you could get more rep if you asked them separately... some people look at a wall of words and go "tl;dr"*"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It was declined automatically by the system after [3 users reviewed](https://superuser.com/review/close/708687) it stating that it should be left open.

While there are indeed two problems listed in the question they appear, at a glance, to be very closely related and could actually have the same root cause.

The "asking too many questions" reason for closure usually means that they are asking for things that are largely unrelated or might not have a common problem. A question asking "How does the power button make a computer turn on? How does USB transfer power?" *should* be closed as too broad. A question saying "software X gives me error Y. I also get error W when I do Z" could be the same problem.

In this case it looks a lot like the two problems listed are part of a core problem and providing information on both could help someone to diagnose it better. Knowing both problems right away, rather than having to hunt through the users other questions, is a Good Thing (tm) in this case.

It is a bit of a judgement call as to how broad is too broad, but generally if it is asking unrelated questions then that is definitely too broad. For closely related problems a couple of listed problems may well not be "too broad".

Comment: +1, not just for the nice interview, but especially: "Knowing both problems right away, rather than having to hunt through the users other questions, is a Good Thing (tm) in this case."  So having the 2nd question provides extra detail which makes the 2nd question not only tolerable, but beneficial and therefore preferred.  Another way of looking at this is that really this is just one core question (or problem), even if the specific wording states multiple questions.  There appears to be one main thing trying to get resolved here.